# Uibutton titlelabel shadowoffset property is not behaving properly in ios 7

Tags: ios, ipad, uibutton, ios7, shadow

I am using the below code to get a shadow to button title label.

```
theCuLabel.titleLabel.shadowColor=[UIColor blackColor];
theCuLabel.titleLabel.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(-3.0,2.5);
```

In IOS 6 its working properly like below

But in IOS 7 its not working as expected like below

I didn't find solution for this, can any one tell me the solution or any update in IOS 7 that happened for this.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: If you are using shadows in iOS 7, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi Thanks 4r your kind reply, then how can give a shadow to uibuttontitle label.. in ios 7 and should support 4r ios 6&5 as well

Comment: @WrightsCS how can I set text shadow color in ios 7+ ?

Answer (score 2):

```
[button setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

this is the correct method to set the shadow color for a UIButton.
I have tried this and is working in all versions.

Comment: grt thanks a lot, its working in all versions now...small change but grt