# iOS:UIButton's title shadow color not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

```
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    btn.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
```

When I run this on ios7, the button has no shadow at all. Give your suggestion.

Comment: u can use layers for that

Comment: You want to add shadow on button or button title?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uibutton titlelabel shadowoffset property is not behaving properly in ios 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142652/uibutton-titlelabel-shadowoffset-property-is-not-behaving-properly-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with following code for give shadow of button's title

```
[button setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And if you want to give shadow on button then read following link.

[Add border and shadow to the buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923443/add-border-and-shadow-to-the-buttons)

Answer (score 4):

first add "QuartzCore" library to ur project and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` this to ur class and do somthing like this

```
 btn.titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;//set preferred color
 btn.titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;//set opacity
```